# Links from HTTPS topbar aren't HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, ssl

On the HTTPS version of Stack Exchange, all links are HTTPS, except some links on the topbar. I am mainly concerned about links in the inbox.

Comment: HTTPS isn't officially supported yet.

Comment: This is now the case, either by site-relative or HTTPS directly: you're landing on `https://`